# Get Facebook Users Access Token

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to get the access Token of a user with his FacebookId, Application Id and Application secret ?

PS : The user has already accepted to use the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the access_token of the user at the time he adds the app, or when he login again using the app. Not at a later moment than that.

You can use an app access_token which doesnt expire and is valid from the point the user adds your app. But keep in mind, it has limited retrieval capabilities comparing a user access_token.

Comment: After long searching, i confirm it's not possible. Thanks.